# Is there an equivalent of partial application for return values?

Tags: c#, clojure, functional-programming, naming, partial-application

If papply returns a function of less arity than an input function, is there a similar FP operation with returns a function which returns a value regardless of the value of the input function? If so, is there a C# equivalent?

Consider a C# function that returns `void` which you want to convert into an expression, and you've done this many many times by writing an anonymous function wrapper like `(args) => f(args); return null;`.

In C#,

```
public Func<T1, T2, ..., T8, TResult> WhatIsMyName<T1, T2, ..., T8, TResult> (Action<T1, T2, ..., T8> action, TResult value = default(TResult))
{
    return (t) => { action(t); return value; }
}
```

which you would ideally call like `FP.WhatIsMyName(voidfunc)` and so **avoid having to cast**.

In Clojure,

```
(defn whatismyname? [f x] 
  (f)
  x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a method that creates the anonymous function for you.

```
public Action<T> Ignore<T,TResult>(Func<T,TResult> func)
{
    return (args) => { func(args); return; }
}
```

Although your code technically returns args, which would be the following format.

```
public Func<T,T> Ignore<T,TResult>(Func<T,TResult> func)
{
    return (args) => { func(args); return args; }
}
```

In either case you can pass it into another method like this `Method(Ignore(DoSomething));` or you can call it yourself like this `Ignore(DoSomething)(1);`.

Comment: I'm willing to write a method, if necessary, if I know what to name it.

Comment: @davidzarlengo: The method you wrote seems to work, you would just have to write it once for each arrity. (Generics can't support variable number of inputs)

Comment: I ended up just writing another anonymous lambda returning null.  I don't think C# is expressive enough to remove this kind of duplication.

Answer (score 2):

In functional programming, you'd probably use function composition to augment or modify a result. For your example, you simply compose the existing function with a constant one, e.g. given `f`:

```
val f' = const 0 o f
```

where `o` is function composition (like in math) and `const 0` creates a constant function always returning 0 (for any argument). Those are standard combinators, which you can define as follows:

```
fun (g o f) x = g (f x)
fun const x y = x
```

Comment: Function composition seems like it's on the right track.  Do you know if there is a way to set this up in C# built into the standard library?

Comment: @davidzarlengo: The only functional things in C# are related to LINQ, so very few of the standard methods are available. F# has lots if you are looking for a language in .NET that is designed for functional programming.